# Document ID URL Delay - What is the Delay?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We enabled Document IDs for our company SharePoint Online; I was quite happy to find out about this feature as we definitely can make very good use of it. We had in the past problems with references between documents that were moved around.

So Document IDs come to help. Great, fantastic!

However, as I was testing it, the very first test went wrong. Got the Document ID link, sent it to someone, asked to access the file. All good.
Then moved the file.
All wrong.

The link refused to work as it was pointing to the previous location.
I thought there was something wrong in the settings of this mecahnism - but there are really few settings you control from the admin pages.

After a few minutes (10? 15? 20? 17.5?), the link automagically appeared. Yay!

So this IS working. But WHAT in the name of God do I have to do in order to know WHEN changes will be propagated through the bowels of SharePoint?

How am I to instruct the users that: hey, this is a super cool feature here, akin to permalinks - but whenever you move documents around, you have to wait a bit for changes to propagate. How long? Um... sorry, I can't tell you that information.

Any help on understanding this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whether you move the file to the same site collection library or another site collection library?

Comment: Basically, I moved the file in the same folder, on the same site.

Answer (score 0):

In the same folder? When I want to move a file into the same folder, it will show the error message "The item is already in this location".

[image]

Whether you mean the subfolder in the fold? I test in this situation, the Document ID for this file does not change, the link is accessed.

Comment: Apologies as I rushed writing the above and introduced confusion. I meant I moved it in a sub-folder of the original folder - basically in another location, in the same site.I would like to understand WHEN would the link would become available, once the file is moved. It takes several minutes for it to update - how can I explain this to my team? How many minutes, where is that configured etc?

Comment: I test in my SharePoint Online. When I move the document to a subfolder, the Document ID link is broken. After few minutes about 3 minutes, the Document ID link will be accessed. It's a possibility that SharePoint Online takes time to refresh the Document ID link in the back end. It's a weird behavior. I suggest you open a service request to ask Microsoft how does it work.